# DMARC only get reports if emails fails authentication

Tags: domain-name-system, dkim

I have setup DMARC on DNS

```
v=DMARC1; p=none; sp=none; fo=1; ri=3600; rua=mailto:report@domain.com; ruf=mailto:report@domain.com
```

I have set `fo` to `1` but I still get reports about emails that passed the authentication!? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fo` provides additional details for failed messages, it would not filter successful email statistics. Any report is up to the receiver to respect, there no requirement to send forensic reports as some may give undesired details about internal email routing.

I'd also suggest using separate emails for forensic reporting.

Comment: but what is the difference between `rua` and `ruf` ? :)

Comment: Rua is report uri aggregate vs forensic

Comment: which will the failed reports be sent to?

Comment: Forensic failed reports go to ruf.